# How to query + Reindex in AWS hosted Elasticsearch outside of Kibana

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have a problem in which I need to query for a subset of records on a large index containing a high volume of records, whilst running a Painless script with the search query to augment the result. The (much smaller) result is to be saved in a secondary index for later use. In a different SO question: [Reindex part of Elasticsearch index onto new index via Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072212/reindex-part-of-elasticsearch-index-onto-new-index-via-jest), I mentioned this is possible through the Kibana interface, but there does not seem to be a Java library that can accomplish what I need. Has anyone ever accomplished a query within a _reindex operation outside of Kibana? I am leaning toward using the URLConnection family in Java, but am looking for suggestions and advice at this point.

Comment: Do you must to use Java? Becouse if not, you can use any rest client with "Reindex by query" query. This query support Painless script like this: 
<pre>
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter",
    "version_type": "external"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.foo == 'bar') {ctx._version++; ctx._source.remove('foo')}",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
</pre>
Or you can use Cerebro application as UI for Elasticsearch management

Comment: I need to use Java to interface with the ES cluster, so, yes, I am somewhat tied to the language.  Also, I am using a Jest client (due to AWS not allowing transport client access), and the closest thing I can see to what you are describing is the Reindex.Builder() method, which I am having trouble executing painless scripts with.

Comment: Essentially I want to do what you are describing, POST a _reindex query that looks something like this:    POST _reindex?slices=10&wait_for_completion=false
{ "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source":{
    "index": "my_source_index",
    "size": 5000,
    "query": { "bool": {
      "filter": { "bool" : { "must" : [...
        ]}}}}
      ]}}
    }}
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my_new_temp_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "<My Painless Script>"
       
      "lang": "painless",
      "params" : { ... }
    }
  }    Can I do that as a payload in HttpUrlConnection ?